# Convert letters to lower case

Tags: python, regex

I use the following with respect to letters from any language:

```
text = regex.sub("[^\p{alpha}\d]+"," ",text
```

Can I use `p{alpha}` to convert letters to their lower case equivalent if such an equivalency exists? How would this regex look?

Comment: Please don't add taglines to your posts, and use `Ctrl+K` or the code button `{}` to format your code, not `<pre>` tags.

Comment: I'm removed the [nsregularexpression] tag because I really doubt you're using ObjectivePython with an NSRegularExpression object from your example.

Comment: Why the regex and not str.lower() ?

Comment: What does `\p{alpha}` mean?  (I can't find any reference to this syntax in the documentation of the `re` module.)

Comment: … I see: you're using the regex module (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), not the standard re module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can find your answer here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub

You can provide a tolower function that takes a match object to the sub method which will return replacement string

Answer (score 56):

```
>>> re.sub('[AEIOU]+', lambda m: m.group(0).lower(), 'SOME TEXT HERE')
'SoMe TeXT HeRe'
```

Comment: I actual need this answer for my case. Convert only a sub string to lower case.

Comment: ahhh Steven... very clear logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As oxtopus suggested, you can simply convert letters to their lowercase version with `text.lower()` (no need for a regular expression).  This works with Unicode strings too (À -> à, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `re.findall("([A-Z]+)", text)` to use whatever regex you need.  This will just go through the matches, and replace each match with its lowercase equivalent:

```
text = 'ABCDEF_ghjiklm_OPQRSTUVWXYZ'
for f in re.findall("([A-Z]+)", text):
    text = text.replace(f, f.lower())
print text
```

Output is:

```
abcdef_ghjiklm_opqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

in languages like Perl or Js the regex engine supports \L -- python is poor that way